# Can VRRP be used between 2 interfaces on the same node instead of between 2 nodes?

Tags: cisco, router, switch, static-routes, vrrp

I have two 3750's joined together with a stackwise cable.  I have a connection between one of the 3750's physical port and a gateway router.  Last week one of the 3750's failed due to power issues, which caused me to lose connectivity to the Gateway Router.  I am looking at using either weighted static routes :(, or VRRP :)to create redundancy between these 3 network elements. I have read that I can use VRRP for master and backup interfaces on the same node, instead of master and backup routers?  If so, can anyone help me with this solution, as I have no lab to test this.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're making this much hard than it has to be.
What's wrong with LACP or just letting STP keep a link in standby?

Comment: I thought spanning tree was used for switches.  What would I use on the router side being that I can not put 2 ports in a single vlan?

Comment: You didn't mention what kind of router you were using; some have built in switching ability too, hence the STP remark. Otherwise LACP would be very easy compared to VRRP.